# Angularjs how to enable html or the entire app or entire page

Tags: angularjs

In Angularjs I must to use ng-bind-html to inject an HTML (a text with HTML elements like 
) to an element.
In my app I need to do it for many elemnts.
Is there a way enable the entire app (or an intire html page)?

Comment: There's no reason you need to use `ng-bind-html` for every element, so you must be doing something strange. Please read [ask] and prepare a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.